# Chrome leaks memory when simply adding and removing SVG elements

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, svg

Continuing this question: [Task manager shows memory leak, but Heap snapshot doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467112/task-manager-shows-memory-leak-but-heap-snapshot-doesnt)

I managed to create a very simple example, which illustrates this leak, here is full source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>svg test</title>



        <script type="text/javascript">

            var svg;
            var interval;
            var svg;

            window.onload = function(){
                createSVG();
                start();
            }

            function start(){
                interval = setInterval(createElements, 100);                
            }

            function createSVG(){

                var div = document.getElementById("svgdiv");
                div.innerHTML = "";

                svg = createSvgElement("svg");
                svg.style.position = "absolute";
                svg.style.width = "600px";
                svg.style.height = "500px";
                svg.setAttribute("version", "1.1");
                div.appendChild(svg);
                createElements();               
            }


            function createElements(){

                removeElements();

                for(var i = 0; i < 500; i++){
                    var element = createSvgElement("circle");
                    element.setAttribute("r", Math.random() * 10);
                    var transform = "translate(" + Math.round(Math.random() * 600) + "," + Math.round(Math.random() * 500) + ")";
                    element.setAttribute("transform", transform);
                    element.setAttribute("fill", "#CC0000");
                    svg.appendChild(element);
                }
            }

            function removeElements(){
                while(svg.hasChildNodes() ){
                    svg.removeChild(svg.lastChild);
                }               
            }


            function createSvgElement (name) {
                return document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", name);
            }

            function stop(){
                clearInterval(interval)
            }


        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:#FFFFFF">
        <div id="svgdiv" style="width:600px; height:500px;"></div>
        <input type="button" value="start" onclick="start()">
        <input type="button" value="stop" onclick="stop()">
    </body>
    </html>
```

If I run this script, Chrome keeps eating the memory until it crashes. Other browsers don't. Instead of removing children one by one I also tried to clear it in a fast way by setting innerHTML="", but it's the same.

I enabled an experimental feature of Chrome which shows the kind of memory is used. The "Pages structures" memory is increasing a bit (however the HTML remains the same and there are no detached DOM objects), but the most memory goes to "Other" section.

If I stop the script and force GC to do it's job, the memory decreases by only few kilobytes. However if I wait for a minute or two, the memory is cleaned almost to a initial level. I know that my script is quite intense, but this happens also if I run it every 1 or two seconds only - I think that's quite enough for GC to do it's job. And I know GC is working, as other kind of memory is released. Could this be a Chrome bug? Maybe I should do something before removing the elements?

Comment: Yeah, looks like a bug to me

Comment: I reported this as a bug to Google, please add a comment what you were able to reproduce it: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=172221&can=4&q=svg&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20OS%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was indeed bug in Chrome, which was fixed some time later:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=172221&can=4&q=svg&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20OS%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary

Answer (score 1):

I managed to slow it down but it is still leaking. I also recreated the test using Raphael.js which did not leak. But when I was testing I found that it was when it was appending the circles. So Raphael must be doing something to stop it from leaking at that point.

Comment: Try commenting out `element.setAttribute("fill", "#CC0000");`. I noticed that there was a major decrease of Memory used and was actually able to be collected.

Comment: Well, but it shouldn't be like this. I use setAttribute a lot to set all the properties of the svg element.

Comment: It only appears to be when changing colour of elements.

Comment: The funny thing is that for some cases `setAttribute` is actually the non-leaking variant (and this is probably why Raphael.js does not show the same problems). I found out that with Chrome 31 using `setAttribute(null, "transform", "transform(0,0")` does *not* leak memory, however doing the same via the Javascript API (`element.transform.baseVal.appendItem(...)`) prevents the memory from being reclaimed. In fact as soon as you do `var a= element.transform.baseVal;` The element is never ever garbage collected again.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if it would be of much help, but if you define "var svg" only once,
 then memory-consumption ( in Task manager) is not rising that fast
 and also stop() function does work after that

Comment: svg is defined only once. element is defined each time, but it's a new object, so I think it's quite OK.