# Memory leak in Task Manager even if Chrome Heap Snapshot shows zero delta

Tags: google-chrome, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

I am investigating a JS memory leak issue using `Chrome DevTools`. Using heap snapshots and doing comparison, I was able to root cause the component responsible for leaking the memory.
Problem I am seeing is that after the fix, even if Chrome DevTools shows no leak, Windows Task Manager shows increase in memory with usage.
Below are the heap snapshots of before and after fix.

Before fix:
[image]

After fix:
[image]

Am I missing anything here? Is Chrome DevTools somehow showing wrong result?
I read a similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467112/task-manager-shows-memory-leak-but-heap-snapshot-doesnt). But it isn't of much help.

Comment: Chrome uses incremental garbage collection which rarely compacts the heap if your app isn't generating a lot of garbage. Wait a minute or two and it should go down.

Comment: @wOxxOm My worry is the Task manager which shows the same amount of memory leak even if Chrome says everything is fine (no detached nodes)

Comment: I waited for ~5 minutes and it's almost the same

Comment: Sounds like something to report on https://crbug.com.

Comment: This seems to be common issue. I wonder if noone has reported it yet.